# Sed replacing mixed-case words with lower-case, while keeping all uppercase words unchanged

Tags: regex, bash, unix, sed

I have files containing (Twitter) tweets like this:

```
GP 02\/14: POP LOH!!! ^^ Photo credits: @joleneqjm @ Marina Floating Platform
```

I need to convert the tweets to lower-case to reduce the vocabulary size. But I don't want to convert POP to pop since POP is an acronym and has special meaning.

So the desired output is:

```
GP 02\/14: POP LOH!!! ^^ photo credits: @joleneqjm @ marina floating platform
```

Is there a way to achieve this using sed or any other bash tools in a one-line fashion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the below sed command,

```
sed -r 's/\b([A-Z][a-z]+)/\L\1/g' file
```

OR

```
sed -r 's/\b([a-zA-Z]*([A-Z][a-z]|[a-z][A-Z])[A-Za-z]*)\b/\L\1/g' file
```

The above sed command would capture the words which starts with an uppercase letter and the following one or more lowercase letters. Then converting the characters inside the captured group to lowercase will give you the desired output.

Comment: This will fail for single letters and words with all uppercase, like `A NICE Flower` gives `A NICE flower`

Comment: @Jotne: the requirement says 'all caps (like POP) should be unchanged'. You can complain that 'oTher mixeS' are not translated; indeed, even 'FloWer' is only converted to 'floWer'.  It is fixable with a slightly more complex regex: `s/\b[a-z]*[A-Z]+[a-z][a-zA-Z]*\b/\L\1/g`. That requires a word starting with zero or more lower-case letters, one or more upper-case letters (so there's something to case-convert), one lower-case letter (so it isn't all upper case), and zero or more other letters. That doesn't handle `mixeS`: use `s/\b([a-z]*[A-Z]+[a-z][a-zA-Z]*|[a-z]+[A-Z])\b/\L\1/g` to do so.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Thanks for the regular expression. It's very helpful since in Twitter the cases are rather noisy. The cases you mentioned do exist

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I did thought that `POP` etc is a kind of header of the message or code for it and should not be translated.  It may be the best solution to find a trigger point and make lower case after that point.  OP says mixed case should be change so that includes `GoPro` as you made a solution for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk` solution.  It will change all to lower case starting from `6` field.

```
cat file
GP 02\/14: POP LOH!!! ^^ Photo credits: @joleneqjm @ A NICE Marina Floating Platform
```

```
awk '{for (i=6;i<=NF;i++) $i=tolower($i)}1' file
GP 02\/14: POP LOH!!! ^^ photo credits: @joleneqjm @ a nice marina floating platform
```

It changes words with single characters `I am`, words with all uppercase `NICE` and words like this `GoPro` to: `i am`, `nice` and  `gopro`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/((\<[A-Z]+\>\W*)*)(\w+)/\1\L\3/g' file
```

This leaves alone uppercase words and lowercases everthing else.